# Passing List<T> through a bundle

Tags: android

I am currently working on an Android assignment for uni and i have a bit of a problem with lists.

Basically i have been following a guide on using a list of type class (in my case its contacts) to make a custom listAdapter for a list view.

on my main Activity i have a List (contacts is a class to hold 2 strings, type and number)

i then get all the numbers and their type from a selected contact in the contacts list. then for each one add create an instance of the class and add that to the list.

once that is done i make a new intent (which is basically an Activity which has a list view but in theme of a dialog) once declared the intent i do a i.putExtra and put a name and the name of my list ( i must stress that i had this working fine with an arraylist not a list.. confusing)

then on my listview activity i do a bundle b = getintent().getextras();

then try to do List myContacts = b.get.... thers nothing which matches a list, theres an arraylist and everything i try kinds of messes up the stuff on the tutorial i read.

if i post the link to tutorial and my source code it might make more sense.
As allways i appreacte any input at all

thanks Vade

Link: http://dustinbreese.blogspot.com/2009/12/creating-listview-with-alternating.html

main source code:

```
 protected void getContactInfo(Intent intent)
{
     ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>() ;
     String name ="";
   Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);      
   while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
   {           
       String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
       name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 

       String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

       if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
           hasPhone = "true";
       else
           hasPhone = "false" ;

       if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
       {
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);

        while (phones.moveToNext()) 
        {
         String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
         String type = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
         contacts.add(type);
         contacts.add(number);

            //phoneNumber.add(new String("Hello"));





        }
        phones.close();
       }
   }
   cursor.close();


  Intent i = new Intent(this,ContactPicker.class);
  i.putExtra("PHONENUMBERS", contacts);

  startActivity(i);

}
```

List View Source: oh i should stress that i got it working with the following, but i can see some bad coding practice here!

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle nBundle  = getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<String> myArray = nBundle.getStringArrayList("PHONENUMBERS");
    List<Contacts> myContacts = getData(myArray);

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactPicker);
    //lv_arr = (String[])myArray.toArray(new String[0]);
    //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ContactPicker.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lv_arr));

    ListAdapter adapter = new ContactsAdapter(this,myContacts,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, new String[] {
            Contacts.KEY_TYPE, Contacts.KEY_NUMBER}, new int[]{
            android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2});
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


    //
    private List<Contacts> getData(ArrayList<String> array){
        List<Contacts> myContacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
        int myArrayLength = array.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < myArrayLength;)
        {
            String type = array.get(i);
            ++i;
            String number = array.get(i);
            ++i;
            myContacts.add(new Contacts(type,number));

        }
        return myContacts;

    }

}
```

EDIT:

After reading the comments below this post i tried this and wanted to check to see if it is exceptable (it works):

Created a class called ContactsList looks like this:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class ContactsList implements Serializable   {

    private List<Contacts> innerContacts;

    public ContactsList(List<Contacts> contacts){
        this.innerContacts = contacts;
    }
    public List<Contacts> getList()
    {
        return this.innerContacts;
    }
}
```

then on my main i did

```
ContactsList l = new ContactsList(contacts);
Intent i = new Intent(this,ContactPicker.class);
i.putExtra("PHONENUMBERS", l);
```

then on my ContactPicker Activity i did this:

```
Serializable l = nBundle.getSerializable("PHONENUMBERS");
    ContactsList cl = (ContactsList)l;
    List<Contacts> myContacts = cl.getList();
```

Just wanted to make sure that doing it this way was acceptable
thanks

Comment: I think you can pass the OBJECTS using putExtras(); but only those who implements Parceable. [Android Parcable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29). Edit: in your case i m not sure but List<String> is not parceable object to be passed via putExtra();

Comment: you can pass objects that are serialized.   create an object which implements Serializable and make sure that object includes your List<T>

Comment: You shouldn't pass large objects or even collection of objects from activity to activity via intent. Try to store the data somewhere you can access it centrally (e.g. in Application class or database).